# Convert column to rows in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a scenario where I need to convert column to rows. I have two tables `table1` and `table2` with the following structure

Table1:

```
 Col11    Col12    Col13
 -------------------------
 200      text     55
```

Table2:

```
 Col1     Col2
 --------------------
 Col11
 Col12
 Col13
```

In need the following result from the above two tables

```
 Col1     Col2
 --------------------
 Col11    200
 Col12    text
 Col13    55
```

Is it possible to do this by using temp tables ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using `UNION ALL`:

```
SELECT 'Col1' AS Col1, Col1 AS Col2
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Col2', Col2
FROM mytable

UNION ALL

SELECT 'Col3', Col3
FROM mytable
```

`Table2` doesn't seem to play any role in producing the required result set. So it is left out in the above query.

Answer (score 1):

you can use cross apply or UNPIVOT to get

```
select  
  coll,colvalue
from PivotColToRow
cross apply
(
  select 'col1', col1 union all
  select 'col2', col2 union all
  select 'col3', col3  
) c (Coll, colvalue);
```

Using UNPIVOT

```
select col,colvalue
from PivotColToRow
unpivot
(
  colvalue
  for col in (col1, col2, col3)
) unpiv;
```

try this